# Make a field optional in a form only when I am editing

Tags: symfony-forms

I created a symfony form for two actions (creation and edition) and I want to put one of the fields of the form optional only when I edit

Comment: Please add the code for your form class.

Comment: ->add('name', null, [
                'label'=> 'asset.form.name.label',
                'attr' => [
                    'maxlength' => 255,
                    'placeholder' => 'asset.form.name.label',
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length(['max' => 255]),
                ]
            ])

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a `data_class` and Doctrine:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $object = $options['data'] ?? null;
    $isEdit = $object && $object->getId();

    $builder->add('name', null, [
        'required' => !$isEdit,
        ...
    ]);
}
```

On create, the form either contains no underlying object or an underlying object without an id, since the object has not been saved to the database yet when the form is built.

On edit, the form contains an underlying object with an id.

So, get the underlying object from the form with `$options['data']` and check if it is not null and has an id.

If an object with an id exists, we know we're on edit (`$isEdit` will be true) and can use that to set the required property.